# Why Chome Secure Shell SSH extension dose not work within iFrame

Tags: ssh, google-chrome-extensions, iframe

Secure Shell Chrome works fine for me, it's great!
Now I'm trying to put in a desktop html using iFrame, but it does not work.

It works well in separate browser window

```
<a target="_New" href="chrome-extension://pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo/html/nassh.html">
SSH root@test New Window</a>
```

But it does not work for iFrame

```
<a target="iframe1" href="chrome-extension://pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo/html/nassh.html">
SSH root@test iFramed</a>
<iframe name="iframe1" id="iframe1" width="90%" height="400px" src=""/>
```

Does anyone know a workaround? thanks

Comment: I can't find any references to cite, but this is due to the security policy for the `chrome-extension://` protocol.  Allowing remote pages to load extensions in an iframe would allow remote pages to probe which extensions you have installed.

Comment: Also, check the developer console (F12) for error details.